# CLI command table in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I have a simple command line interface in my AVR microcontroller firmware, based around a structure like this:

```c
typedef struct {
    const char *name;
    const char *usage;
    const char *help;
    void (*handler)(char **last);
} command_t;

extern command_t *cli_commands[];
```

I'd like to be able to declare commands in different modules in as DRY a way as possible. So far, I have it so that I define my functions like this:

```c
COMMAND_IMPL(replay, "replay <n>", "Replay frame n") {
    // 'last' argument is for strtok_t
}
```

and then I have to have this in one of my `.c` files:

```c
COMMAND_DECL(list);
COMMAND_DECL(clear);
COMMAND_DECL(replay);

COMMAND_TABLE
    COMMAND(list)
    COMMAND(clear)
    COMMAND(replay)
END_COMMAND_TABLE
```

My macros look like this:

```c
#define COMMAND_IMPL(name, usage, help) \
    static void cli_handle_##name##_command(char **);\
    command_t cli_##name##_command = {#name, usage, help, cli_handle_##name##_command};\
    static void cli_handle_##name##_command(char **last)
#define COMMAND_DECL(name) extern command_t cli_##name##_command;
#define COMMAND_TABLE command_t *cli_commands[] = {
#define COMMAND(name) ((command_t *) &cli_##name##_command),
#define END_COMMAND_TABLE NULL };
```

Can it be done any better than that? The project already tied to avr-gcc, so I don't mind if it's a GCC-only solution. A solution that makes of linker features is okay too (I'm compiling to an ELF). I'm thinking perhaps I could put the command entries in a different section, and have that linked to somewhere known, but I can't think how it would get terminated then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `section` attribute like so (this is how the linux kernel exports its functions):

```
#define COMMAND_IMPL(name, usage, help) \
    static void cli_handle_##name##_command(char **); \
    command_t cli_##name##_command __attribute((section("commands"))) = { #name, usage, help, cli_handle_##name##_command }; \
static void cli_handle_##name##_command(char **last)
```

Then, you can use an `ld` script (see http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html) to get the address of the begin/end of the 'commands' section:

```
...
SECTION commands ALIGN(4) : {
    commands_begin = .;
    *(commands)
    commands_end = .;
}
```

Finally, declare two variables:

`extern command_t commands_begin, commands_end;`

You can then use the address of these variables to get the whole list of command structures, i.e.

```
for (command_t *cmd = &commands_begin; cmd != &commands_end; cmd++)
    ...
```

Notice how `&commands_end` points just beyond the last command.

Comment: Note that you don't need a linker script for this. gcc will make 2  symbols available for your sections. You can simply declare `extern command_t  *__start_commands;` and `extern command_t  *__stop_commands;` to get pointers to the beginning and end of the "commands" section that was created.

Comment: How do I control which segment that section goes in? I need it to go in the text segment (I think -- it's AVR pgmspace data).

Comment: I get this error from ld:

/opt/local/lib/gcc/avr/4.7.2/../../../../avr/bin/ld: section cli_cmdtable loaded at [000000000000175a,0000000000001771] overlaps section .data loaded at [000000000000175a,000000000000193b]

Comment: @nos ah yea I figured gcc created some sort of start/end symbols, I just couldn't find them